# Blazor index content not loading after login and authentication check

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0

I started a blazor server app from scratch, no template.

I have an authentication check component with the following code

```
@inject ApiAuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager;

@code {
    private async Task CheckAuthenticationAsync()
    {
        var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Redirect to the login page
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/account/login");
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await CheckAuthenticationAsync();
    }
}

@functions {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

And my main layout which looks as follows

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<AuthenticationCheck>
    <header>
        <Nav />
    </header>

    @Body

    <footer>
        All Rights Reserved
    </footer>
</AuthenticationCheck>
```

This works to redirect unauthenticated users to the login page

once logged in, authentication works ok, the page displays blank.

index page as follows

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>Welcome to your new app.</p>
```

and app.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <AuthenticationCheck>
                    </AuthenticationCheck>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

I found the  approach whilst searching how to implement this but i cannot find the link.
What have i missed here that is preventing index loading correctly?

I moved the auth check to before the content

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<AuthenticationCheck />

<header>
    <Nav />
</header>

@Body

<footer>
    All Rights Reserved
</footer>
```

This has the desired result but there is a momentary flick of the index page before the redirect to login occurs which does not look nice